# Google Sheets API node.js only output recent date

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am currently working on updating my Raspberry Pi 3 / Magic Mirror for work to put in my office.

I am an Aquatic Safety Coordinator and I check the chemical logs of my pools regularly.

I have it to where its getting the first three columns for right now and the first columns is a date/time format. The data is found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Y5Syg-z63YGfsX7nPYOXRFZ-t_jB23QUKCLZAT4BYA/edit#gid=1833266067)

the code I have right now is

```
var row = rows[i];

console.log('%s, %s', row[0], row[1], row[2]);
```

Might be a noob question but how would I only display the most recent row of data according to the first column which is date and time?